# How to create alias for the two POJO Parent classes in hibernate using Criteria API

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api

I need to have equivalent Criteria API in Hibernate:

```
mysql> select c.name,t.teamname from club c,team t;
+---------+----------+
| name    | teamname |
+---------+----------+
| Arsenal | Team A   |
| thiru   | Team A   |
+---------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

will it possible to have alias for two parent Pojo classes in CreateCriteria
```

Comment: Did you create the mapping for Club and Team. Are they related through some foreign key relationship or you just want to perform a cartesian product between the two?

Comment: Both have relationship in table as well as in POJO classes

Comment: If `club` or `team` are having any property refering to the other entity, you can use that to create alias. Sharing your mapping would help us in replying. Also, the sql query you gave perform cartesian product (there is no join condition), do you really want to perform the Cartesian product?

Comment: I need that sample how will you createAlias over CreateCriteria to have two parents POJO classes with aliases

Answer (score 0):

Create a POjo class

```
public class POJO {
  private String name;
  private String teamname;

  public POJO() { }

  ...
}
```

Now you can get the value injected via property methods or fields instead, removing the need for explicit constructors.

As i am not sure about relationship between team and club.... As i am assuming team as parent and club as child ......

EG:

In criteria :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Team.class);
   criteria.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("teamname"),"teamname"));
                        .add(Projections.property("club.name"),"name"));
                        criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(POJO.class));
```

In HQL :

```
List resultWithAliasedBean = s.createQuery(
  "select c.name as name,t.teamname as teamname from club c,team t")
  .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(POJO.class))
  .list();

POJO pojo = (POJO) resultWithAliasedBean.get(0);
```